# Clicking an anchor tag with certain hyperlink

Tags: javascript, anchor, href

How would I access(throught JavaScript) an anchor element without it having any attributes except "href"?

Example: `<a href="http://www.example.com/forum/addPost/id=5"`

Okay, now the "id" in the URL changes, so can I use like `substr()`, or something else to "cut" the href attribute value in half. So it would now be `href="http://www.example.com/forum/addPost/id="`.

Now what if there were multiple anchor tags on the page, how would I 'access' the anchor tag with the specific href?

Comment: Could you please give an example? It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Are you asking how you can programmatically click the link using javascript, or are you asking how, when a user clicks the link, you can send the to a modified url instead of the one in the href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not opposed to using jQuery, this is pretty straightforward.  To access a hyperlink if you have the ID value to search with:

```
var $anchor = $('a[href$="<ID value>"]');
```

The $anchor object would be a reference to the DOM element whose href ends with the ID that you specify.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *document.links* collection that is all the links in the document, so:

```
var links = document.links;
var re = /www\.example\.com\/forum\/addPost/;

for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {

  if (re.test(links[i].href)) {
    // do stuff with the href value
  }
}
```